# Two Tensorflow errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn

Me and a friend are tunning parameter for our neural network. The code down below is what we have got so far.

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
import numpy as np

ds = pd.read_csv(
    "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/data/abalone_train.csv",
    names=["Length", "Diameter", "Height", "Whole weight", "Shucked weight",
           "Viscera weight", "Shell weight", "Age"])
print(ds)

x_train = ds.copy()
y_train = x_train.pop('Age')
x_train = np.array(x_train)

def create_model(layers, activations):
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    for i, nodes in enumerate(layers):
        if i == 0:
            model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(nodes, input_dim=x_train.shape[1]))
            model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation(activations))
            model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3))
        else:
            model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(nodes))
            model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation(activations))
            model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3))

    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('sigmoid'))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, verbose=0)

layers = [[20], [40,20], [45, 30, 15]]
activations = ['sigmoid', 'relu']
param_grid = dict(layers=layers, activations=activations, batch_size = [128, 256], epochs=[30])
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, cv=5)

grid_result = grid.fit(x_train, y_train)

print(grid_result.best_score_,grid_reslult.best_params_)

pred_y = grid.predict(x_test)
y_pred = (pred_y > 0.5)

cm=confusion_matrix(y_pred, y_test)
score=accuracy_score(y_pred, y_test)

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=30, callbacks=[cp_callback])
#steps_per_epoch
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=2)

probability_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    model,
    tf.keras.layers.Softmax()
])

probability_model(x_test[:100])
```

when running we get these errors:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:5 out of the last 13 calls to <function Model.make_test_function.<locals>.test_function at 0x0000028D61D54550> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. For (1), please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), @tf.function has experimental_relax_shapes=True option that relaxes argument shapes that can avoid unnecessary retracing. For (3), please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/performance#python_or_tensor_args and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for  more details.
```

and:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "woe.py", line 41, in <module>
    grid_result = grid.fit(x_train, y_train)
  File "C:\Users\jeroe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 72, in inner_f
    return f(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jeroe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py", line 761, in fit
    self.best_estimator_ = clone(clone(base_estimator).set_params(
  File "C:\Users\jeroe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 72, in inner_f
    return f(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jeroe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 96, in clone
    raise RuntimeError('Cannot clone object %s, as the constructor '
RuntimeError: Cannot clone object <tensorflow.python.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn.KerasClassifier object at 0x0000028D64D48A90>, as the constructor either does not set or modifies parameter layers
```

We tried lots of things like changing x_train into a tensor and chaning tf.karas.layer.activation(activations) into tf.keras.layers.activation('relu'), but we still get stuck at these errors. Does anyone have a solution on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The first is just a warning for retracing, which will reduce performance. You can get values from a dataframe with df.values, so instead, you would have

```py
x_train = ds.copy()
y_train = x_train['age'].values
x_train = x_train.values
```

I believe this is the error, though I cannot test it to ascertain.

Comment: I seem to be getting the exact same problem, only now the warning is mentioned at least 20 times before the exact same error is mentioned.